# Add event listeners to buttons within a ListView - WinJS

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs

I have a list of items within a ListView which contain buttons. I can't find a way to add event listeners to the buttons...

---

This is the code:

JS:

```
downloadsListView = document.getElementById('downloads').winControl
downloadsListView.itemDataSource = JobList.dataSource
downloadsListView.onloadingstatechanged = function() {
      var _this = this;
      return WinJS.Utilities.query("button.play_pause_button", document.getElementById('downloads')).forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element);
        return element.onclick = _this._play_pause_download;
      });
    };
```

---

I can assure that the function does loop over the buttons via the console output. But clicking on the buttons fires nothing.

I hope someone can help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I think Dominic's comment is your best bet. The [ListView.itemTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700705.aspx) page on MSDN says...

> **Adding interactive elements to an item template** The item template can contain most other controls, but it can't contain a FlipView or
>   another ListView.
>
> Normally, when the user interacts with an element, the ListView
>   captures that interaction and uses it to determine whether the user
>   selected or invoked an item or is panning through items. For an
>   interactive element, such as a control, to receive input, you must
>   attach the win-interactive class to the interactive element or one of
>   its parent elements. That element and its children receive the
>   interaction and no longer trigger events for the ListView.
>
> When you attach the win-interactive to an element in a item template,
>   be sure that the element doesn't fill the entire item, otherwise the
>   user won't have a way to select or invoke that item.
>
> To add interactive elements to your item template, you must use a
>   templating function instead of a WinJS.Binding.Template.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just add an event listener to the ListViewItem, that fires when the user taps/clicks on the element? This is the proper way of doing it.

ListView has onItemInvoked. Mor info on that can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211827.aspx).

Example in your case:

```
 <div id="downloads" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
data-win-options="{oniteminvoked : _play_pause_download}">
</div>
```

Comment: If you do have specific interactive elements inside your items, you can also add 'win-interactive' to the element you wish to allow interactivity too